# Calculate the sum of values using window function in SQL

Tags: sql, window-functions

I have a few tables and my goal is to create a parquet-table format dataframe in order to use it later.

My tables consists of clients data (one table shows specific data on my clients, second shows all the information on their transactions). Basically, one table's line shows one payment made by the client in a specific date and how much did a client actually paid.

Example:

Table1:

| id | name | email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | sta@example.com |
| 2 | Danny | dany@example.com |

Table2:

| id | pay_date | pay_num | pay_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-20 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2022-01-25 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | 2022-02-15 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2022-03-10 | 2 | 400 |

I want to create a joined table with the information presented as of 2022-03-31 (in other words to get information only on the last payment for each client close to 2022-03-31).

In order to do this I use the following code:

```
create table new stored as parquet as select * from (Select * from
(select table1.id, name, pay_date, pay_num, pay_sum, row_number() over (partition by table2.id order by pay_date DESC) rn
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where pay_date <= cast("2022-03-31" as timestamp))
where rn = 1) t
```

As a result I get the following table:

| id | name | pay_date | pay_num | pay_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 2022-01-25 | 2 | 200 |
| 2 | Danny | 2022-03-10 | 2 | 400 |

Everything is ok, but I need to get a sum of all payments made by my clients during their all payments in a column pay_sum.

In other words my goal is to create a table like this:

| id | name | pay_date | pay_num | pay_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sta | 2022-01-25 | 2 | 300 |
| 2 | Danny | 2022-03-10 | 2 | 450 |

I tried to sum the values, but the result is the same - 200 and 400 instead of 300 and 450

How is it possible to get the sum of all the payments made by the clients as of 2022-03-31?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can skip the window function, and just use aggregate functions.

```
select 
  table1.id, 
  name,
  max(pay_date), 
  max(pay_num), 
  sum(pay_sum) 
from 
  table1 
  inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id 
where 
  pay_date <= cast("2022-03-31" as timestamp)
group by 
  table.id, 
  name
```